# Could you fix my code to compute lexical richness?

Tags: python, lexical

I am trying to use LexicalRichness (https://pypi.org/project/lexicalrichness/). I copied and pasted the code:

```
import lexicalrichness
from lexicalrichness import LexicalRichness

text = """Measure of textual lexical diversity, computed as the mean length of sequential words in
                a text that maintains a minimum threshold TTR score.

                Iterates over words until TTR scores falls below a threshold, then increase factor
                counter by 1 and start over. McCarthy and Jarvis (2010, pg. 385) recommends a factor
                threshold in the range of [0.660, 0.750].
                (McCarthy 2005, McCarthy and Jarvis 2010)"""

use_TextBlob=True
lex = lexicalrichness(text)

print(lex.words)
print(lex.terms)
print(lex.ttr)
print(lex.rttr)
print(lex.cttr)
print(lex.msttr(segment_window=25))
print(lex.mattr(window_size=25))
print(lex.mtld(threshold=0.72))
print(lex.hdd(draws=42))
```

But it doesn't work (the error message is: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)

Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Replace `lex = lexicalrichness(text)` by `lex = LexicalRichness(text)`: the first in lower case is the module, the second in camel case is the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line for capitalisation: `lex = LexicalRichness(text)`